# Controlling tabs from java code

Tags: android, xml, tabs

I have a project with 4tabs in it. All four tabs are within the activity_main xml file. The MainActivity Java file uses the tabhost to set the content of the tabs. One of my tabs has a list view and the other a map. Do I carry out all these events(loading the map,setting the list view) in the MainActivity class or I can implement a class for each layout so that the class is called when the focus changes to that tab? Kind of a newbie need some serious help. Not very familiar with tabs as well. Thanx. Dont know what sample code to attach as I havent tried much except implement some things in a different class and that never worked.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tab content should be an activity (or at least what i found in code samples), first time you activate a tab it will its activity `onCreate()`, and then if you clicked a tab that was already loaded that will call its `onResume()`. 
[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) you can find a step by step tutorial for using tabs.

Comment: found this easy to understand in accordance to my level of Android programming right now. thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).

For each of your tabs create a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and add it to the `FragmentTabHost`.

Here's a quick [tutorial](http://www.betteropts.com/fragmenttabhost-tutorial-using-fragment-as-tab-content-and-keep-navigation-history-for-each-tab/).

Comment: havnt yet properly looked into fragments but i will soon